# How to get a typed response from json-ld and hydra in Angular 13?

Tags: angular, json-ld

I'm trying to make a paginated table in Angular. For that I'm using a backend which returns a json-ld and hydra context response. I want to map that to a model. Typed responses with regular json works fine, but the problem arises with json-ld/hydra context.

I need to get a typed response from the format at the bottom of this post. This is what I have so far:

A list interface

```
export interface List<T> {
  totalItems: string;
  members: T[];
}
```

Company model

```
export class CompanyModel {

  id: number | null;
  companyName: string;
  logoUrl: string;
  users: any;

  constructor(id: any = 0, companyName: string, logoUrl: string, users: any) {
    this.id = id;
    this.companyName = companyName;
    this.logoUrl = logoUrl;
    this.users = users;
  }
}
```

And a service (CompanyService) which has a `get()` function to retrieve all (paginated) models.

```
  get(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<List<CompanyModel>>(this.endpoint + "/companies", {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Accept':  'application/ld+json'
      })
    });
  }
```

This is the response I get:

```
@context: "/api/contexts/Company"
@id: "/api/companies"
@type: "hydra:Collection"
hydra:member: [{@id: "/api/companies/1", @type: "Company", id: 1, companyName: "Huels-Weber",…},…]
hydra:search: {@type: "hydra:IriTemplate", hydra:template: "/api/companies{?companyName}",…}
hydra:totalItems: 500
hydra:view: {@id: "/api/companies?page=1", @type: "hydra:PartialCollectionView",…}
```

I need the totalItems and members to be mapped to an object as I've explained above. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to map the server response to fit the `List<CompanyModel>` type

It can be done using the rxjs `map` operator

```
 get(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<List<CompanyModel>>(this.endpoint + "/companies", {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Accept':  'application/ld+json'
      })
    }).pipe(
        map((res: any) => ({
          totalItems: res['hydra:totalItems'],
          members: res['hydra:member'],
        }))
      );
  }
```

### Edit

You can update the `List` interface so that you don't have to map anything..

```
export interface List<T> {
  'hydra:totalItems': number;
  'hydra:member': T[];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work and maps correctly. However, it's not really what I was looking for. I want to prevent having to map or do any crazy modifications.  Isn't it possible to add hydra:totalItems and members in the List model so that I don't have to map data?

Comment: @user2879055 yes you can have them in the List interface by wrapping their names with double quotes ("")

Comment: That seems to work properly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can parse Rest API response and map to your app's schema :

```
get(): Observable<List<CompanyModel>> {
  return this.http.get<any>(this.endpoint + "/companies", {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Accept':  'application/ld+json'
    })
  }).pipe(
    map((json: any) => {
      const members: CompanyModel[] = json['hydra:member'].map(jsonMember =>({
        id: jsonMember.id,
        companyName: jsonMember.companyName,
        ...
      });

      return {
        totalItems: json['hydra:totalItems'],
        members
      }
    })
  );
  }
```

Of course this could be improved by :

- including a typescript model of your 'JSON-LD' response
- checking if input data are well formatted, with correct values

Hope this will help.